# Unable to deploy contract on Ropsten network

Tags: solidity, truffle, ropsten

When I try to migrate contract to Ropsten Network (`truffle migrate --network ropsten`) it keeps migrating the contract on the net with id 4447 unless Ropsten is the **only** network configured in `truffle.js` file.

Here is my configuration

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
  ropsten: {
    network_id: 3,    
    host: "localhost",
    port: 9545,
    gas: 6712388,
    gasPrice: 65000000000
  }
},
optimizer: {
  "enabled": true,
  "runs": 200
}
};
```

Snippet of the generated JSON of my contract after `truffle migrate --network ropsten`

```
"networks": {
    "4447": {
      "events": {},
      "links": {},
      "address": "0xf204a4ef082f5c04bb89f7d5e6568b796096735a",
      "transactionHash": 
"0x35abaaed14ab37937fdcf38551ee1b6068c5950ad4d59b8df65a6ad852892b13"
    }
  },
```

Version

```
-> % truffle version
Truffle v4.1.11 (core: 4.1.11)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)
```

Configuration with multiple network as requested by @Roman Frolov

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
      development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*",
      gas: 6712388,
      gasPrice: 65000000000
    }
  ropsten: {
    network_id: 3,    
    host: "localhost",
    port: 9545,
    gas: 6712388,
    gasPrice: 65000000000
  }
},
optimizer: {
      "enabled": true,
      "runs": 200
    }
    };
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of your truffle.js with multiple networks configuration?

Comment: Added to the original question

Comment: Why are there two lines which say `networks: {`? Is that correct? There don't seem to be enough `}`... There are *six* `{` but only *five* `}` Also, the indentation of both of the configurations seems wrong -  although that is only a presentation issue.

Comment: Yes it is... My fault!
Now it's correct!